# Python Image.fromarray() doesn't accept my ndarray input which is built from a list

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to visualize a list of 2048280 integers which are either 1's or 0's. There is a function that outputs this list from a (width=1515 height=1352) image file. The function

```
test_results = [(numpy.argmax(SomeFunctionReturningAnArrayForEachGivenPixel))
                    for y in xrange(1352) for x in range(1532)]
```

returns an array of size 2058280 (=1515x1352) = as expected. For each y, 1532 values of 1/0 are returned and stored in the array.

Now, when this "test_results" array is returned, I want to save it as an image. So I np.reshape() the array to size (1352,1515,1). All is fine. Logically, I should save this list as a grayscale image. I changed the ndarray data type to 'unit8' and multiplied the pixel values by 127 or 255.

But no matter what I do, the Image.fromarray() function keeps saying that either 'it cannot handle this data type' or 'too many dimensions' or simply gives an error. When I debug it into the Image functions, it looks like the Image library cannot retrieve the array's 'stride'!

All the examples on the net simply reshape the list into an array and save them as an image! Is there anything wrong with my list?

I have already tried various modes ('RGB' , 'L' , '1'). I also changed the data type of my array into uint8, int8, np.uint8(), uint32..

```
            result=self.evaluate(test_data,box) #returns the array
            re_array= np.asarray(result,dtype='uint8')
            res2 = np.reshape(reray,(1352,1515,1))
            res3 =(res2*255)

            i = Image.fromarray(res3,'1') ## Raises the exception
            i.save('me.png')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a grayscale image, don't add the trivial third dimension to your array.  Leave it as a two-dimensional array: `res2 = np.reshape(reray, (1352, 1515))` (assuming `reray` is the one-dimensional array).

Here's a simple example that worked for me.  `data` is a two-dimensional array with type `np.uint8` containing 0s and 1s:

```
In [29]: data
Out[29]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Create an image from `255*data` with mode `'L'`, and save it as a PNG file:

```
In [30]: img = Image.fromarray(255*data, mode='L')

In [31]: img.save('foo.png')
```

When I tried to create the image using `mode='1'`, I wasn't able to get a correct PNG file.  Pillow has some known problems with moving between numpy arrays and images with bit depth 1.

Another option is to use [`numpngw`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpngw).  (I'm the author `numpngw`.)  It allows you to save the data to a PNG file with bit depth 1:

```
In [40]: import numpngw

In [41]: numpngw.write_png('foo.png', data, bitdepth=1)
```

Comment: Thank you! Well, I certainly did try the two-dimensional array but expected it to work only in '1' mode. The strange thing was that when I debugged into Image.py, my array was different to a grayscale Image object in its arr['strides']